# SQL JOIN a table and GROUP BY to get correct row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Here is the situation, i for the tables forum_topics, forum_replies and users.
Where the _topics contains all the topics, the _replies contains all posts and the users contain all users.

I'm trying to list the topics as:

(Subject)***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***(Time of last reply)

(Topic created by username)***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**(Last reply by)

For now, the "subject" and "topic created by username" displays just fine, however, the time of the last post and user who posted it is wrong.

SQL:

```
 SELECT 
forum_topics.id,
forum_topics.category,
forum_topics.subject,
forum_topics.created AS topiccreate,
forum_topics.createdby AS topiccreatedby,
forum_replies.topic,
forum_replies.created AS repliecreated,
forum_replies.createdby AS repliecreatedby,
usertopic.firstname AS topicfirstname,
usertopic.lastname AS topiclastname,
userreplie.firstname AS repliefirstname,
userreplie.lastname AS replielastname,
usertopic.id as topicid, 
userreplie.id

FROM forum_topics

JOIN forum_replies ON forum_replies.topic = forum_topics.id
JOIN users usertopic ON forum_topics.createdby = usertopic.id
JOIN users userreplie ON forum_replies.createdby = userreplie.id

WHERE forum_topics.category =  '1'
GROUP BY forum_replies.topic
ORDER BY forum_replies.created DESC
```

How can i get the "Time of last reply" and "Last reply by" to display correct? I've tried removing the Group By, and then it retrieves all the posts, however i just want the very latest post-data for each topic.

As for now when using GROUP BY, it retrieves all the topics just once (correct) but the last reply by and time of the last reply is not displaying correct as it seems to retrieve the data for the first post of each topic.

Hope you understand my question! :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more condition to get the latest reply.  Here is how you would do it in the `join` clause:

```
FROM forum_topics
JOIN forum_replies ON forum_replies.topic = forum_topics.id
JOIN users usertopic ON forum_topics.createdby = usertopic.id
JOIN users userreplie ON forum_replies.createdby = userreplie.id
JOIN (select topic, max(created) as maxcreated
      from forum_replies
      group by topic
     ) frmax on frmax.topic = forum_replies.topic and
                frmax.maxcreated = forum_replies.created;
```

I don't think you will need the `group by` after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing both group  by and order by in your SQL query and check.